# Converting To Disjunctive Normal Form

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, disjunctive-normal-form

> By writing the function in disjunctive normal form, design an equivalent system of switches, that is one having an equal switching function.

$ f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1(x_2(x_1 \oplus x_3) \oplus x_3 \overline{x_2}) $

I've had a look in my book and there is very little mention of disjunctive normal form. I've had a look online and I really have no idea to go converting this function into it. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us fix some notation first. We use $\phi_1 \wedge \phi_2$ to denote "$\phi_1$ *and* $\phi_2$" (this is called a *conjunction*), $\phi_1 \vee \phi_2$ to denote "$\phi_1$ *or* $\phi_2$" (this is called a *disjunction* and $\neg \phi_1$ to denote *not* $\phi_1$ (this is called a *negation*). We use $x_1, x_2 \ldots$ to denote Boolean variables and abbreviate $\neg x$ as $\overline{x}$. A *literal* $\ell$ is either a Boolean variable $x$ or a negated Boolean variable $\overline{x}$.

A Boolean formula $\phi$ is a *disjunctive normal form* if $\phi$ is of the form

$$\bigvee^{m}_{i=1} \bigwedge^{m_i}_{j=1} \ell_{ij}$$

A Boolean formula $\phi$ is a *conjunctive normal form* if $\phi$ is of the form

$$\bigwedge^{m}_{i=1} \bigvee^{m_i}_{j=1} \ell_{ij}$$

That is, $\phi$ is a *conjunction* of *disjunctions* of literals.

A central theorem is that for every Boolean formula $\phi$ we can construct an equivalent formula in disjunctive normal form and an equivalent formula in conjuctive normal form.

To do this, use the identities

$$\neg (\phi_1 \vee \phi_2) \equiv \neg \phi_1 \wedge \neg \phi_2$$
$$\neg (\phi_1 \wedge \phi_2) \equiv \neg \phi_1 \vee \neg \phi_2$$
$$\phi_1 \vee (\phi_2 \wedge \phi_2) \equiv (\phi_1 \vee \phi_2) \wedge (\phi_1 \vee \phi_3)$$
$$\phi_1 \wedge (\phi_2 \vee \phi_2) \equiv (\phi_1 \wedge \phi_2) \vee (\phi_1 \wedge \phi_3)$$

to push the negations inwards and to group the disjunctions together and group the conjuctions together.

A worked example may be helpful here. Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7nyonAsIo8 .

Comment: I am still very lost and confused here. Am I right in saying that the function I have is will take quite a lot of steps to convert? Am I right in saying that it would look like $ f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1 \wedge (x_2 \wedge (x_1 \vee x_3) \vee (x_3 \wedge \neg x_2) $

Comment: No, I am afraid not. The expression $x_1 \wedge (x_2 \wedge (x_1 \vee x_3) \vee (x_3 \wedge \neg x_2)$ is obviously not in disjunctive normal form, as it not a disjunction of conjunctions of literals.

Comment: Sorry I meant in terms of the original function before it was converted. So far I've gotten to the point of $ x_1 \wedge ((x_2 \wedge x_1) \vee (x_2 \wedge x_3) \vee (x_3 \wedge \neg x_2)) $ and not sure where to go next from here. Thanks.

Comment: Use the distributive laws to push the conjunctions inwards.

Comment: $ (x_1 \wedge x_2) \vee (x_1) \vee (x_1 \wedge x_2) \vee (x_1 \wedge x_3) \vee (x_1 \wedge x_3) \vee (x_1 \wedge \neg x_2) $. This is what I have finally ended up with. Am I right in saying this is in disjunctive normal form?

Comment: Yes, this is a disjunctive normal form (how do you check that it is?)